# NameError: uninitialized class variable @@config in CassandraObject::Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cassandra

Following the docs when I do `widget = Widget.create(name: 'Acme', price: 100)`

I get

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/gotime-cassandra_object-4.11.4/lib/cassandra_object/model.rb:20:in `config'

/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/gotime-cassandra_object-4.11.4/lib/cassandra_object/connection.rb:24:in `cql'

/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/gotime-cassandra_object-4.11.4/lib/cassandra_object/connection.rb:31:in `block in execute_cql'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the config file was not under the initializer folder, once I put it there it worked.